# Custom Domain AWS API-Gateway 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Custom domain has been mapped with AWS API-Gateway and using my custom domain name randomly gives following error.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried different domain mappings and have also used root (/) as a default but changing mappings does not improve reliability. Using AWS URL (https://xxxxxx.execute-api.xxxxx.amazonaws.com) always works relibily so I think it is a custom domain problem.

I can reproduce this with the custom domain on using Postman and Curl command, using AWS URL never gave an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was our DNS and not AWS, DNS was showing random results due to the wildcard.

Comment: What was the fix?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan fix was to correct DNS at our end. DNS should always return to correct cname entry. In our case, it was sometimes giving IP from a wildcard.